# Javascript convert date and time today and save .txt file using its format

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Target: When download linked is clicked, a .text will be automatically downloaded named the date and time format for today. (eg: 7-3-2021 04:04:00 PM or which ever format is applicable as long as the date and time is on the name)

This is the code for the link:

```
<a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none"><button class="btn btn-block btn-warning">Download</button></a>
```

While here is the code for the function:

```
(function () {
        var textFile = null,
          makeTextFile = function (text) {
            text = text.replace(/\n/g, "\r\n");
            var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});

            // If we are replacing a previously generated file we need to
            // manually revoke the object URL to avoid memory leaks.
            if (textFile !== null) {
              window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
            }

            textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

            return textFile;
          };

          var create = document.getElementById('create'),
            textbox = document.getElementById('todayGeneratedReport');

          create.addEventListener('click', function () {
            var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
            link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value);
            link.style.display = 'block';
          }, false);
        })();
```

The code is good but I'm having issues on how to make it happen. Currently, when download link is clicked, a info.text file is being saved but my target is to saved it using the date and time format when the link is clicked.

Do I need to create another function and import it to the download property of the link? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides modifying link `href` and `style`, you can modify its `download` attribute as well. Here's one way to do it:

```
create.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var filename = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US') + '.txt';
   
  var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
  link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value);
  link.setAttribute('download', filename);
  link.style.display = 'block';
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 provides the `a[download]` attribute which lets you rename a file. This example will download `link.txt` and rename it `today.txt`.

```html
<a download="today.txt" href="link.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none"><button class="btn btn-block btn-warning">Download</button></a>
```

So if you want to be named as today's date then you can just put it under the download attribute and it will be automatically renamed.

To do this dynamically you can edit a small part of your code.

```js
create.addEventListener('click', function () {
            var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
            link.download = formatDate(new Date());
            link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value);
            link.style.display = 'block';
          }, false);
```

And you can define `formatDate` as you wish:

```js
const formatDate = (date)=>date.now();
```

Comment: That is correct but how would I import this to make that happen?

Comment: ```Date.prototype.yyyymmddhhmmss = function() {
  var yyyymmddhhmm = this.yyyymmddhhmm();
  var ss = this.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + this.getSeconds() : this.getSeconds();
  return "".concat(yyyymmddhhmm).concat(ss);
};

var d = new Date();```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's suggestions. They've been a big help in order for me to resolved it.

What I've done is this:

```
var fileRenamed = new Date().toLocaleString();

            Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
              var yyyy = this.getFullYear();
              var mm = this.getMonth() < 9 ? "0" + (this.getMonth() + 1) : (this.getMonth() + 1); // getMonth() is zero-based
              var dd = this.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + this.getDate() : this.getDate();
              return "".concat(yyyy + "-").concat(mm + "-").concat(dd + "-");
            };

            Date.prototype.yyyymmddhhmm = function() {
              var yyyymmdd = this.yyyymmdd();
              var hh = this.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + this.getHours() : this.getHours();
              var min = this.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + this.getMinutes() : this.getMinutes();
              return "".concat(yyyymmdd).concat(hh + "-").concat(min + "-");
            };

            Date.prototype.yyyymmddhhmmss = function() {
              var yyyymmddhhmm = this.yyyymmddhhmm();
              var ss = this.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + this.getSeconds() : this.getSeconds();
              return "".concat(yyyymmddhhmm).concat(ss);
            };

            var d = new Date();

            var fileRenamed = d.yyyymmddhhmmss();

          create.addEventListener('click', function () {
            var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
            link.setAttribute('download', fileRenamed + '.txt')
            link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value);
            link.style.display = 'block';
          }, false);
```

I used o-o's answer as per advised because of time format in every country. It's working now :-)

Appreciate your help.